# Where can I find clientside Websockets examples?

Tags: html, websocket

I'm not currently trying to set up a server with Websockets.  Eventually I will, but I first just want to see a short working example of websockets, connecting to a third party server.

I found a short example here: http://www.websockets.org/about.html and here http://blog.chromium.org/2009/12/web-sockets-now-available-in-google.html but couldn't get either of them to work.

Do you know where I can find a couple/few confirmed **working** client side examples of websockets?  I believe websockets.org provides an echo address ws://websockets.org:8787 (so please don't tell me "just set up a server yourself!).  Thanks!

Comment: http://jxs.me/2010/09/07/github-live-via-eventmachine-websockets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) works quite well for me, takes 2 minutes to set up and start testing

Answer (score 0):

[jWebSocket](http://jwebsocket.org/) is a custom implementation of web sockets but they're compatible with native browser web sockets and they have a number of demos available, including a really basic hello world and a chat client. Terrible framed website though, so you'll have to go there and click the links on the left side to get to the demos.